# How can i extract values from textboxes and put them into array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to extract 12 textboxes values and put them into array, and check each value inside the array!

Comment: Please post some code examples, what you have tried already, and be more specific about what you need help with. (You can use jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net and provide a minimal workspace of code)

Comment: start by given them a common class name

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = []

var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')

;[].forEach.call(checkboxes, function (check) {
  arr.push(check.value)
})

console.log(arr) // all the values
```

Explaining the code:

- create an array (`var arr = []`)
- loop through all the checkboxes (`;[].forEach.call(checkboxes,`)
- add their values to the array (`arr.push(check.value)`)

Comment: whoopsies, I added an explanation

Comment: This is better; I’m just going to add that using `map` instead of `forEach` is a bit more appropriate here.

Comment: "I need to extract 12 textboxes values". Although the answer ends up being more or less the same, it it's only a 1 line question...

Answer (score 0):

If you have it into one form use FormData API. Here is [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData). 
For example:

```
var formData = new FormData(formInstance);
```

Where formInstance is reference to form. And then iterate of formData.entries()

```
for (let input of formData.entries()) {
        data.push(input[1]);
    }
```

Where data is array